# Deactive link in h2

Tags: 7, nodes, navigation

I created a custom node.tpl.php file with the following code:

```
<?php
 /**
  * @file
  * Default theme implementation to display a node.
  */
?>


<div<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print $user_picture; ?>

  <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
    <div class="submitted">
      <?php print $submitted; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if (!$page && $title): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print render($title_link); ?></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

  <div<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      print render($content);
    ?>
  </div>

  <?php print render($content['links']); ?>
  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
</div>
```

Everything works, but the `<h2>` tags come with link I don't want.

Instead of `<h2 datatype="" property="dc:title"><a href="/node/10">NEWSSSSS</a></h2>`, I want `<h2 datatype="" property="dc:title">NEWSSSSS</h2>`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sometimes asking a question helps you figure out the problem out, clears your thoughts. way to go

Comment: Remember to write an answer, when you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this line and worked!

`<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print render($title_link); ?></h2>`

change to

```
<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print render($title); ?></h2>
```

`($title_link)` ----> `($title)`